# The domain of a continuous real function must be connected?

Tags: analysis, functions

The domain of a continuous real function must be connected?

For instance, the function
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\ \ \, 1 & \text{if $x \in (1,2)$} \\
-1& \text{if $x \in (2,3)$}
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies the requirements of a continuous function with domain $D=(1,2) \cup (2,3)$, but there is a jump in the graph.

Comment: To answer your first question: no.  As an example, every real-valued function defined on the integers is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

A continuous function must be continuous at every point in its domain. That is satisfied for the function you've defined because we can approach any point in the domain from the left and from the right and get the same result, roughly speaking.

However, including $2$ in the domain would make the function discontinuous at $2$ regardless of the value of $f(2)$.

Comment: Thank you guys!!!

Answer (score 1):

No, the domain of a continuous function does not have to be connected. You can even have some isolated points in your domain and still have a continuous function. It defies the intuitive high school concept of continuity but as long as the inverse image of every open set is open ( like in your example )  your function is continuous.